# Convert Realm list of Strings to Array of Strings in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, realm

I'm just starting up with RealmSwift, and I'm trying to store an array of Strings in Realm. It doesn't work, so now I'm using `List<String>()` as an alternative. However, how do I convert these Realm Lists back to `[String]` again? And if I can't do that, are there any alternatives?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show what code you've tried and include the Realm Object you're using? There could be a number of answers and those may or not be correct depending on your use case so to accurately answer can you describe what you're trying to do. Also, please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Update your question, include your code and we'll take a look.

Answer (score 14):

> However, how do I convert these Realm Lists back to [String] again

You can simply cast `List` to `Array`, because `List` has [`Sequence Support`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/List.html#/Sequence%20Support):

```
let list = List<String>()
let array = Array(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that by converting to an array you'll lose the 'dynamic' quality of a Realm collection (i.e. you'll receive a static array, whereas keeping the original List will provide automatic updating should the source change). But you can create an array by using an extension, e.g.:-

```
extension RealmCollection
{
  func toArray<T>() ->[T]
  {
    return self.compactMap{$0 as? T}
  }
}
```

Then use:-

```
let stringList = object.strings.toArray()
```

Where `object` is the realm object, and `strings` is your field.

Comment: Thank you. I would prefer to keep the list, but it doesn't work, so unfortunately this is what I'm going to have to do.

Comment: This array of strings is the value in a dictionary, and it doesn't let me have a dictionary of type `[Int: List<String>]`

Comment: That almost sounds like a modelable type. Maybe it could be represented as an array of objects, with an int id and list of strings. Difficult to guess without knowing more of the problem. I'd suggest you mark this as answered, and consider asking another question about modelling this (or carry on anyway).

Comment: @Gargo What does that mean? What doesn't work? What 'custom classes' are you talking about, and how is that relevant to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the details. how to assign an array in the realm list model.

```
jim.dogs.append(objectsIn: someDogs)
```